# Rails dynamically rendered js partial doesn't works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I've been struggling with a dynamically render partial in my app. I have a modal that creates a new record and closes itself after that. I have a create.js.erb that is responsible for close the modal and append that new record to the page like that:

```
$('#div-id').append('<p>Record was successfully created.</p>');
setTimeout("$('.close').click();", 3000);

$("#another-div").append('<%= escape_javascript(render(partial: "new_record")) %>');
```

It renders the partial and show it on my page. However, this appended partial has a link that should open up a model when clicked, but that doesn't work right after the render, I actually have to reload the page and click on this record button to see the modal.

To show this modal I have a backbone view which listen to an event based on it's attribute:

```
events:
  'click a[open-modal]': 'showModal'
```

Maybe it has something to do it this backbone view, but I haven't done much backbone + coffeescript before.

Sorry for the newbie question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with backbone either, but the root issue is that the listener for the link is not being attached to dynamically added page elements.  If you were using jQuery, you'd use the [on method](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to ensure that newly added page elements also have listeners attached to them:

```
$(document).on 'click', '.some_link_class', (event) ->
  #Do stuff!
```